# I can't scroll down on my website.No idea how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

so I can't scroll down on my website, but I want to add more content, I tried everything. Tried to increase the height in CSS but not helped.I'm a beginner in web development please help me!
Thanks!
Maybe the problem is somewhere in the CSS code as I think. Maybe in the body tag, but I'm not sure in this
The webpage will be looking a bit weird without the full CSS code.
Here is the code of my website:

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0e0f0f;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}

.menu.active {
  width: 85%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
}

.menu.active .menuContent * {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.menu span {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0e0f0f;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu span i {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 45%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.1s ease 0.1s;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 40%;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60%;
}

.menu .menuContent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .menuContent * {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: #2d3235;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 13px;
  left: 20px;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 13px;
  left: -20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #112b38;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 12px 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul:hover li a {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: .2;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #43bc0b;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!--Ez az Menu kodja-->

  <div class='menu'>
    <span class='toggle'>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </span>
    <div class='menuContent'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Ez az Image slider kodja-->


  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Computers/Laptop_on_Desk_HD_Wallpaper.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Computers/Laptop_on_Desk_HD_Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Computers/Laptop_on_Desk_HD_Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>


    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it would help to see an actual interactive example. However the `overflow: hidden;` on the body is surely what's causing this. I'm not sure why you've put that in, but remove it and it will solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:
`overflow: hidden;`
To
`overflow: auto;`

In `body` css selector

Answer (score 0):

Remove your CSS code from a body element `overflow: hidden;`

```
body {

    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;  
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Runnable solution is [here](https://codepen.io/ddeveloperr/pen/OYVZPJ).